# C# Excel: Programmatically open and copy workbook while ignoring dependency

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm currently trying to write an add-in that takes values from fileA and combine with file1. However fileA requires fileB and fileB requires fileC due to codes written with VBA by previous owner. I only require a certain sheet from fileA but when calling open to fileA, it will also open fileB and fileC.

Is there a way where I can open fileA or copy fileA without opening other files i.e. ignoring dependency? I tried searching online about it but most question and solution given are for files without dependency.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-In project.

Any help appreciated.

Note: I am not allowed to edit the VBA code and I do not need the values in fileA to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the file with `AutomationSecurity` disabled:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
```